# Find a closed formula for the following recursive function

Tags: closed-form

How can I express a closed-form formula for the following equation? 
$$f(n)=f(n-1)+\frac{C}{f(n-1)} $$
Where $C>0$ and $f(0)=\sqrt{C}$.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: An equation I encounter during my research.

Comment: Have you tried working out the first few terms?

Comment: Yep. still I did not observed any behavior of the results

Comment: @user3563894 If it helps, $f_n$ is increasing and divergent.

Comment: You can show that $f()$ will always be of the form $g(n)\sqrt{C}$, and that $g(n)$ satisfies the recurrence $g(n)=g(n-1)+1/(g(n-1))$. This sequence has been studied pretty extensively, I believe. I don't think an explicit form is known, but the asymptotics _are_ known (this shows up in Spivak's _Companion to Concrete Mathematics_ IIRC).

Comment: I know. But I need the exact formula

Comment: There almost certainly is not an exact formula.

Comment: Actually, I take that back - given the nature of the recurrence (if $g(n)=a(n)/b(n)$ then $a(n+1)=a(n)^2+b(n)^2$ and $b(n+1)=a(n)b(n)$, and it's not too hard to show inductively that $GCD(a(n),b(n))=1$ for all $n$) there may be an explicit constant $C$ such that $b(n)=\lfloor C^{2^n}\rfloor$ or some very similar formula — but computing such a C is likely no easier than computing the sequence itself.

Comment: More to the point, given the comment above, the numerator and denominator in the 'exact formula' for $g()$ grow super-exponentially, so they're likely to be beyond reasonable computational limits in very short order; *why* do you need the exact formula?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to represent the formula as $g(n)=a^n/b^n$?

Comment: @user3563894 It can't be that simple; the asymptotics on the formula you give would either be $g(n)\to 1$ or $g(n)\gt c^n$ for some $c\gt 1$, but it doesn't grow that fast. What's more, the terms of the numerator and denominator _must_ grow super-exponentially (I can go into detail on this in an answer, if you want).

Comment: @PierreCarre The point of my (original) comment was that the question for all $C$ comes down to the question for $C=1$; if $g(n)$ satisfies the recurrence for $C=1$, then $f(n)=g(n)\sqrt{C}$ satisfies it for any given $C$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your $f(n) = \sqrt{C} g(n)$, where $g(n)$ is obtained by the recursion
$$ g(n) = g(n-1) + 1/g(n-1)$$
with $g(0)=1$.  The numerators are [OEIS sequence A073833](https://oeis.org/A073833),
denominators [A073834](https://oeis.org/A073834), and $g(n)$ is the fractional chromatic number of the Mycielski graph $M_{n+1}$.  There seems to be no closed-form formula, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do. It seems like
\begin{align}
\frac{f(n)-f(n-1)}{n-(n-1)} = \frac{C}{f(n-1)}.
\end{align}
Let us solve the differential equation
\begin{align}
f' = \frac{C}{f} \ \ \implies \ \ \frac{d}{dx}(f)^2 = C
\end{align}
which means $f^2 = Cx$ or $f(x) = \sqrt{C}\sqrt{x}$. Observe
\begin{align}
\sqrt{C}\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{C}\sqrt{n-1} = \frac{\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{C}}{2f(n)}=\frac{\sqrt{C}}{2\sqrt{n}}\leq f(n)-f(n-1) \leq \frac{\sqrt{C}}{2\sqrt{n-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{C}}{2f(n-1)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but still I need the exact formula. Not an approximation :(

Comment: @user3563894 What makes you believe that there is actually a closed form solution to that difference equation?